# Implementing Multitasking Bar ios7

Tags: swift, ios7, uiscrollview, uikit, uicollectionview

I have trouble implementing the Multitasking UI iOS 7 style. My problem lies in the bottom part of the multitask UI.

[image: Bottom Multitask UI]
I assume this is implemented as UICollectionView and when when you scroll this bit you change the interline spacing via uicollectionview flow layout delegate... That all works fine however when you scroll them the velocity does not feel natural. I presume this is because of the changing line spacing between cells as it scrolls...

Would be great if you guys can give some input!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after hacking a bit more of uiscrollview apparently you can change the content inset to "control" the velocity of the scrollview... I will put a code in github for people once i have finished implementing this

EDIT

This is harder than I thought.... but apparently changing content inset on the fly while you scroll does not create the natural effect like the native multitask bar in iOS7. It is "better" but I am wondering if i am missing something here.... Here is pseudo logic of my code currently...

```js
            let countItems = self.collectionView(self.mainCardCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: 0)
            if countItems >= 6{
                let insetIconOffset:CGFloat = (CGFloat(2) * self.maximumIconSpacing) - (CGFloat(2) * self.minimumIconSpacing)

                
                if scrollView.contentOffset.x < first2Offset{
                    self.interLineSpacing = self.maximumIconSpacing;
                    self.adjustCardInset(0)

                }else if scrollView.contentOffset.x >= first2Offset &&  scrollView.contentOffset.x < first3Offset-1{
                    let offset:CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x - first2Offset
                    let percentage:CGFloat = offset/CGFloat(first3Offset - first2Offset)
                    self.interLineSpacing = self.maximumIconSpacing - percentage*(self.maximumIconSpacing-self.minimumIconSpacing);
                    self.adjustCardInset(2)
                    
                    
                }else if scrollView.contentOffset.x >= last3Offset && scrollView.contentOffset.x < last2Offset {
                    let offset:CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x - last3Offset
                    let percentage:CGFloat = offset/(last2Offset - last3Offset)
                    self.interLineSpacing = self.minimumIconSpacing + percentage*(self.maximumIconSpacing-self.minimumIconSpacing);
                    self.adjustCardInsetRight(2, numberItems: countItems-3)
                    
                    println("card ajust before last 2")
                    //self.adjustCardInset(2)
                    //println("offset \(offset) percentage \(percentage) interlinespacing \(self.interLineSpacing)")

                }else if scrollView.contentOffset.x >= last2Offset{
                    self.interLineSpacing = self.maximumIconSpacing
                    self.adjustCardInsetRight(2, numberItems: countItems-3)
                    
                    println("card ajust after last 2")
                    //self.adjustCardInset(2)
                }else{
                    self.interLineSpacing = self.minimumIconSpacing
                    self.adjustCardInset(2)
                }
            
            }
```